# Stuck on first question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Betty is building a pen in her backyard to hold hens. She has plenty of roofing materials but only enough materials to fence 18 metres on the sides. She wants the pen to be rectangular, but is not sure how long to make each side. **If the length of the pen is *x* m and the width is *y* m, show that y = 9 - x**

I do not comprehend this problem: What am I supposed to be visualising in my head?

Comment: I call bull***. A user with a nicknname as complicated as "foritisirrational" knows how to answer a question that a 10-year old can answer. I say you sir, are a troll.

Comment: @5xum Sir, I am good at English but not very good at maths!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ____
   |    |
   |    | x
   |____|
     y
```

She has enough material for the perimeter to be $18$m. What is the perimeter? There are $2$ sides of length $x$ and $2$ sides of length $y$, so we have that
$$2x+2y = 18$$
Try to simplify this equation to the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Betty can only build a fence with a perimeter of 18m. Considering x to be length of the rectangular pen and y to be its breadth, the perimeter is $2(x+y)$. This must be equal to 18. Therefore, $x + y = 9$ or $y = 9 - x$. Just draw the rectangle out with arbitrary length and breadth and sum the sides. You'll understand it then. You need to work on your imagination and intuitive capabilities as they are really important for mathematics.